# Idiomatic way to iterate over a string and replace value in original string with mapped value

Tags: string, go, range, byte

I have a working solution on iterating over a string and mapping the `rune` to a mapping

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    numToString := map[rune]string{
        '0': "zero",
        '1': "one",
        '2': "two",
        '3': "three",
        '4': "four",
        '5': "five",
        '6': "six",
        '7': "seven",
        '8': "eight",
        '9': "nine",
    }

    testStr := "one two 3 four"
    newStr := ""
    for _, char := range testStr {
        if val, ok := numToString[char]; ok {
            newStr += val
            continue
        }
        newStr += string(char)
    }
    // prints one two three four
    fmt.Println(string(newStr))
}
```

This does what I desire.. however I am curious about a cleaner way (if possible) rather than allocating an entirely new string to build based off the original. If I could modify the original in place while iterating, I would prefer that.

Playground [here](https://go.dev/play/p/7FUliQYO31m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strings.Replacer](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Replacer) to replace strings.

```
var numToString = strings.NewReplacer(
    "0", "zero",
    "1", "one",
    "2", "two",
    "3", "three",
    "4", "four",
    "5", "five",
    "6", "six",
    "7", "seven",
    "8", "eight",
    "9", "nine").Replace

func main() {
    testStr := "one two 3 four"
    newStr := numToString(testStr)
    fmt.Println(newStr)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/hhLC2N6064P